Creating a .NET app which contains two separate WebApplications
I have an app that needs to have two separate web applications, listening on different ports, for different uses.
I feel like the way I'm currently doing it is messy, or possibly dangerous.
My current approach is:

Have my main Program be a subclass of IHostedService
In my static Main(), create an IHostBuilder and configure services with:

services.AddHostedService<MyProgram>();
services.AddSingleton<WebApplication1>();
services.AddSingleton<WebApplication2>();


MyProgram then gets instances of both WebApplication1 and WebApplication2
And then in MyProgram.StartAsync(), I call:

_webApp1.Initialize();
_webApp2.Initialize();
await Task.WhenAll(_webApp1.Start(), _webApp2.Start());
Where Initialize() creates the internal WebApplication using a WebApplicationBuilder
Start() starts the internal WebApplication running



I've had to jump through some DI hoops to get some instances shared between the two WebApplications, so I was hoping there might be a better way of doing this.
My need to have 2 webapps is because it is structured as:
(frontend) <-> [SignalR WebApp <-> internal logic <-> REST API] <-> (other internal services)

I don't understand why this all needs to be in the same app.

There needs to be communication between the two web apps.
In this case, one of them is for SignalR communication with the frontend, and the other is for a REST api for communicating with other services. There needs to be data passed between these two
(edited question to include explanation)

I still can't see a reason why these web applications need to be bundled in a single application

That still doesn't answer why this needs to have 2 different web apps. In fact, the REST API doesn't need to exist at all in your description.

@DavidG there's additional communication going on with other services using the REST API that totally needs to exist for what I'm doing here.

@SecurityHound If I can limit SignalR to only communicate on one port and the REST API to only communicate on another in the same application, then great - that absolutely sounds like a better way to go

@SecurityHound Ignoring, for a moment, how it's built, what I want is a SignalR connection which would include user authentication, and would be accessible from the outside world, and a REST API that is only accessible from other servers in the local network, not the outside world. I currently do that by having the REST API only accessible on a port that isn't visible to the outside world. The question is whether I would create both of these using the same WebApplication, or use two separate ones.

@SecurityHound that's really good to know - I'll go with that approach then
If you want to put that in an actual answer (to this quite down-voted question!) I'll happily accept it, as it's, I think, the information that I was after in the first place

i will pass on that opportunity.

Well I appreciate your help on this! Thanks

first create two separate program.cs file for both application. Use a common IHostedService to manage both web apps.. then create main Program.cs, configure the host to include the two web applications.

If you really want to separate your SignalR and API from each other, you could use one solution with two projects, one for each program. A third project can be used to share the logic between these two projects. A bit more advanced would be to create a NuGet package of the third project, which can be moved outside of the solution entirely.
However, why don't you incorporate SignalR in your API? After all they both serve the same purpose as far as I can tell from your question. Since SignalR uses hubs (which is just another class), I'd imagine it wouldn't be to hard to merge these two things together.

If I can keep them on different ports within the same application, then that would work. They need to only be accessed from different places - I don't want the public internet able to access the REST API

Aaaah okay now I understand. In that case I would use the first solution I gave you.  The two projects can be run separately from each other but share the same logic by using the third project.

I feel like I've explained my problem really badly here. The two web applications need to be access and pass between them the same data, not just have access to the same logic

The simplest method would still be to use one solution and have two projects. You could send HTTP-requests to be able to communicate between these applications, like you do from the client to your SignalR application.
